# Integrating the PAX-A920 with a Flutter web app

Tags: flutter, web, pax

Developing financial web app with Flutter. User payment method: PAX-A920 device. Need to retrieve payment details within Flutter app.

The user can use this device to pay with Visa, Mastercard, or any other payment method.

I want to have the payment details in my app, including the user's name, the paid amount, as well as the date and time of the transaction (the information typically displayed on a receipt).

How to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.